# Find available IP range in mysql table

Tags: mysql, inet-aton

I have following sql. Works fine for searching IPs.
But I also would like to be able so search

```
select * from table 
where (INET_ATON(ip) BETWEEN INET_ATON('10.12.77.1') AND INET_ATON('10.12.77.10') )
limit 30
```

results is fine

```
10.12.77.2
10.12.77.5
10.12.77.6
```

how can I get available IPs like

```
10.12.77.1
10.12.77.3
10.12.77.4
10.12.77.7
10.12.77.8
10.12.77.9
10.12.77.10
```

Is it possible to do in mysql, or should I do this in Java?

Thx

Comment: It ain't clear, what you are asking... Do you want spaces at the start of each ip?

Comment: no no, I want complement of first result. It means all address in range - first result.

Comment: Do it in java etc, this is not a job for sql

Comment: Applying `INET_ATON` on each row is inefficient. Consider storing the values numerically, i. e., the return values of `INET_ATON`.

Comment: Generally, it's best to handle the issue of missing data in the presentation layer/application-level code

Comment: Finally I did in in Java. Thx all for responses.

Answer (score 1):

**Did you try not between :**

```
select * from table 
where (INET_ATON(ip) NOT BETWEEN INET_ATON('10.12.77.1') AND INET_ATON('10.12.77.10') )
limit 30
```

By the way your query is looking  1 to 10, so why limit 30 ?
It should be 10.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) has a `SubnetUtils` class which is easy and useful for IP and Netmask calculations. You can initialize an object with valid netmask values and get `SubnetInfo` class to get various information.

```
SubnetUtils subnet = new SubnetUtils("10.12.77.1", "255.255.255.242");
SubnetInfo subnetInfo = subnet.getInfo();
```